# Looking for dream sequence references

Tags: references

Hello I am in early pre prod for a fantasy type film where a girl jumps from reality to dream world, the dream world is a "golden desert" type, I was just wondering what films I could look at that have dream sequences with interesting uses of sound?

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly recommend looking into Twin Peaks (both the show and movie...whatever you can get your hands on). The film heavily revolves around a series of dream sequences which have outstanding sound design (no surprise since it is a lynch film!).

Trainspotting has a much darker dream sequence, when the protagonist (Ewen Mcgregor) is going through withdrawal at his parents home. Different, but still great sound design.

Cheers!

Comment: Great answer.  The sound design (among EVERYTHING else) in Twin Peaks was amazing.

Answer (score 3):

The Cell

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eCD5Nuoyi4

Answer (score 1):

Some of these are Dream Sequences, some are Drug Sequences and some are Flashback/Forward scenes. They're all pretty interchangeable when it comes to techniques to portray a alternate sort of reality in my opinion.

Inception (probably painfully obvious), The Imaginarium of Dr. Parnassus, The Matrix, Memento, Dark City, Jacobs Ladder, Enter The Void.

That's all off the top of my head that no one else has mentioned yet. If any more come to mind I'll modify my post.

Answer (score 1):

The Conversation has a fantastic dream sequence. It is also a great film for sound!

Answer (score 0):

[Ink](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1071804/) is a cool one to! Its about a group that protects you in your dreams.
And of course  the guy that tries to kill you in your dreams.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few films where there are differences in reality between scenes:

Scott Pilgrim has some interesting dream bits, 
Vanilla Sky would be a really good one as thats all about dreams.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent Nightmare on Elmstreet film.